# Moose method modifiers on DBIx::Class::Schema models in Catalyst

Tags: perl, moose, catalyst, dbix-class

For any given result class MySchema::Result::Foo (built from default schema loader generated 
syntax which uses Moose/MooseX::nonmoose)

If I add a BUILDARGS method wrapper to sanitize the constructor data for a row like so:

```
package MySchema::Result::Foo;
use Moose;
use MooseX::NonMoose;
[etc ..]

around 'BUILDARGS' => sub {
   my $orig = shift;
   my $class = shift;
   delete $_[0]->{not_a_real_column};
   return $class->$orig(@_);
};
```

It works when using the schema directly.
For example the following works as expected: A new row object is created with real_column=>'value' and not_a_real_column removed before ->new is called

```
use MySchema;
my $s = MySchema->connect('dbi:blahblahblah');
$s->resultset('Foo')->new({ real_column=>'value', not_a_real_column=>'some other thing' }); #win
```

However, when using the same schema via Catalyst::Model::DBIC::Schema the order is 
different. The following fails when trying to create a new Foo row object because 
not_a_real_column is invalid. In other words the arguments to new are not run through BUILDARGS before ->new is called.

```
$c->model('MySchemaModel')->resultset('Foo')->new({ real_column=>'value', not_a_real_column=>'some other thing' }); #fails
```

Interestingly enough, if I wrap around 'new' => sub{} instead of around 'BUILDARGS' => sub{} the behavior is the same in both cases, and works fine, but to my understanding Moose dogma states to never mess with new.

Anyone care to help me understand why this is the case, or if there's a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I see, you are using MooseX::NonMoose.

Given that, I have a guess that you need to use FOREIGNBUILDARGS

```
around 'FOREGINBUILDARGS' => sub {
   my $orig = shift;
   my $class = shift;
   delete $_[0]->{not_a_real_column};
   return $class->$orig(@_);
};
```

"MooseX::NonMoose allows you to manipulate the argument list that gets passed to the superclass constructor by defining a FOREIGNBUILDARGS method."
[http://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::NonMoose](http://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX%3a%3aNonMoose)

I really hope this works for you!